# Proving an inequality using the divergence theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, boundary-value-problem

I have a question that reads

> $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}w=\nabla^2w$$
>   for $w(t,\vec x)$ with initial condition $w(0,\vec x) = w(0,x)$ in $V$ , boundary condition $w(t,\vec x) = f(\vec x)$ on $S$ for all $t > 0$.
>
> Show that
>   $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\iiint |\nabla w|^2 dV\le0$$

So far I have

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\iiint |\nabla w|^2 = 
\iiint\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\nabla.(w\nabla w)-w\nabla^2w)dV$$
$$= \iint\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(w\nabla w).d\vec S-\iiint\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(w\nabla^2 w)dV$$
(divergence theorem)
$$=-\iiint\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(w\nabla^2 w) dV$$
($w$ constant on $S$)
$$=-\iiint(\frac{\partial w}{\partial t})^2+(w\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 t}w) dV$$
(using the PDE given).

The first term is then clearly negative, but I'm not sure about the second?

Answer (score -1):

You could try integration by parts on $w \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial^2 t}$, as this would then lead to a square term.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean? How can I integrate this by parts.

Comment: Differentiate the $w$ and integrate the $\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial^2 t}$
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Higher_dimensions

Comment: Notice that the integral is over the space dimensions, so you cannot integrate by parts in time